# Running flutter app after name change is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have recently changed the name of my flutter app. Now, when I try to run the app, the app won't install on the virtual device.

I run it through the flutter run command and this is all I get:

```
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider
enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             19.0s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

I only get this problem after I change the name of the app. I have changed it in the google-services.json as well so it matches what I have in Firebase. However, when I made the changes in my Firebase project the google-services.json file didn't reflect the changes. I don't know if this could be a problem but I did make the needed changes to the file manually.

What do I need to do to fix this issue with name change?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Run `flutter run` with `--verbose` and check if you have any errors there. Include it here in the question

Comment: I had to add 2 answers to the original question because it was too long. Please see the output from the flutter run -- verbose below in both answers.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Here is what I get when I execute flutter run --verbose

```
[   +2 ms] :url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.    
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations' is
c3f21c15ed4d9cea5f863cf5a6e9525c
[   +1 ms] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution   
worker Thread 7,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution   
worker Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main])started.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed.  
Took 0.045 secs.
[        ] > Task :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug' is
04554c6daf7ba3b090832d021fa9a7d7
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug' as it is up-to-date.      
[        ] :url_launcher_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main])completed. Took 0.003 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread      
7,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles' because: 
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles' as it is up-to-date. 
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread      
7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.008 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[includedbuilds,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[includedbuilds,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread       
7,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles' because:  
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles' as it is up-to-date.  
[        ] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread       
7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[included
builds,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[included
builds,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main])     
started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile' because:
[   +1 ms]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution worker Thread 7,5,main])     
completed. Took 0.002 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[included       
builds,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[included       
builds,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[included builds,5,main]) started.    
[        ] > Task :url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish' because:
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish' as it is up-to-date.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[included builds,5,main]) completed.  
Took 0.003 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution        
worker,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.     
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource' because:
[   +2 ms]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed.   
Took 0.003 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[included
builds,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[included
builds,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.  
[   +1 ms] > Task :url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars' is
f7c0e1750aa697f121dda1037ef2fe57
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars' as it is up-to-date.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed.Took 0.004 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[included builds,5,main]) 
started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[included builds,5,main]) 
completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.    
[        ] > Task :url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] Caching disabled for task ':url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar' because:
[   +1 ms]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed.  
Took 0.005 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:assembleDebug (Thread[included builds,5,main])  
started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :url_launcher_android:assembleDebug (Thread[included builds,5,main])  
completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :url_launcher_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.     
[        ] > Task :url_launcher_android:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Skipping task ':url_launcher_android:assembleDebug' as it has no actions.
[        ] :url_launcher_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed.   
Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution     
worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution     
worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.  
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols' as it has no source files
and no previous output files.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed.Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
(Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
(Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars'    
because:
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' as it is       
up-to-date.
[   +1 ms] :webview_flutter_android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution    
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution    
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started. 
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations' is
184fce6507b305085478430d1b802e56
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations' as it is up-to-date.       
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Execution worker,5,main])
completed. Took 0.012 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Executionworker Thread 3,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Executionworker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution worker,5,main])      
started.
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug' is
04554c6daf7ba3b090832d021fa9a7d7
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug' as it is up-to-date.   
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:extractDeepLinksForAarDebug (Thread[Execution worker,5,main])      
completed. Took 0.002 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread   
3,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles'       
because:
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles' as it is
up-to-date.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread   
3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.012 secs.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
(Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread    
3,5,main]) started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles'        
because:
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles' as it is
up-to-date.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles (Thread[Execution worker Thread    
3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution     
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution     
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])
started.
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile' because:        
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile' as it is up-to-date.        
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:prepareDebugArtProfile (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])  
completed. Took 0.002 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[Execution   
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[Execution   
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])started.
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish' because:      
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish' as it is up-to-date.      
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:prepareLintJarForPublish (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])completed. Took 0.002 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution     
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution     
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +1 ms] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])  
started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource' because:        
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource' as it is up-to-date.        
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:mergeDebugJavaResource (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])  
completed. Took 0.006 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[   +2 ms] :webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])        
started.
[   +1 ms] > Task :webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Build cache key for task ':webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars' is
c6c7ef400bb2f7d63221ab44b26cca45
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:syncDebugLibJars (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])        
completed. Took 0.003 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution
worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] producer locations for task group 0 (Thread[Execution worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.     
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) started. 
[   +2 ms] producer locations for task group 0 (Thread[Execution worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed.   
Took 0.0 secs.
[   +2 ms] > Task :webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] Caching disabled for task ':webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar' because:
[        ]   Caching has been disabled for the task
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:bundleDebugAar (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main])
completed. Took 0.003 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread2,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) started.  
[        ] > Task :webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Skipping task ':webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug' as it has no actions.
[        ] :webview_flutter_android:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed.Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 27s
[        ] 348 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 from cache, 339 up-to-date
[        ] Watched directory hierarchies: [C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle,
C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android]
[        ] Build cache (C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\build-cache-1) removing files not accessed on or 
after Wed Jan 10 11:12:34 MST 2024.
[        ] Build cache (C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\build-cache-1) cleanup deleted 237
files/directories.
[        ] Build cache (C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\build-cache-1) cleaned up in 0.929 secs.
[        ] VCS Checkout Cache (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\vcs-1) removing files  
not accessed on or after Wed Jan 10 11:12:33 MST 2024.
[        ] VCS Checkout Cache (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\vcs-1) cleanup deleted 
0 files/directories.
[        ] VCS Checkout Cache (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\vcs-1) cleaned up in   
0.002 secs.
[        ] dependencies-accessors
(C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\7.5\dependencies-accessors) removing files not       
accessed on or after Wed Jan 10 11:12:34 MST 2024.
[        ] dependencies-accessors
(C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\7.5\dependencies-accessors) cleanup deleted 0        
files/directories.
[   +1 ms] dependencies-accessors
(C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\.gradle\7.5\dependencies-accessors) cleaned up in 0.001 secs.[ +550 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 33.9s)
[   +4 ms] Calculate SHA1: LocalDirectory:
'C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'/app-debug.apk
[+2465 ms] √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\aapt dump xmltree
C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml       
[  +89 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\aapt dump
xmltree C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[   +1 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x22
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="14" (Raw: "14")
               A: package="com.kane.dealdiligence" (Raw: "com.kane.dealdiligence")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x22
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xe
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x21
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.READ_CALENDAR")
               E: queries (line=19)
                 E: intent (line=20)
                   E: action (line=21)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.INSERT" (Raw:
                     "android.intent.action.INSERT")
                   E: data (line=23)
                     A: android:mimeType(0x01010026)="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" (Raw:
                     "vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
                 E: intent (line=25)
                   E: action (line=26)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"                     (Raw: "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND")
               E: uses-permission (line=30)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
               E: uses-permission (line=31)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=32)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS")
               E: uses-permission (line=33)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.VIBRATE" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.VIBRATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=34)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" (Raw:        
                 "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
               E: uses-permission (line=35)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.BILLING" (Raw:
                 "com.android.vending.BILLING")
               E: permission (line=37)
                 A:
                 android:name(0x01010003)="com.kane.dealdiligence.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISS                 ION" (Raw: "com.kane.dealdiligence.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION")
                 A: android:protectionLevel(0x01010009)=(type 0x11)0x2
               E: uses-permission (line=41)
                 A:
                 android:name(0x01010003)="com.kane.dealdiligence.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISS                 ION" (Raw: "com.kane.dealdiligence.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION")
               E: application (line=43)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="deal_diligence" (Raw: "deal_diligence")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterMultiDexApplication" (Raw:
                 "io.flutter.app.FlutterMultiDexApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"   
                 (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=49)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0b0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.kane.deal_diligence.MainActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.kane.deal_diligence.MainActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=64)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw:      
                     "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0b0001
                   E: intent-filter (line=68)
                     E: action (line=69)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=71)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=75)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel                   _id" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rest of the output from flutter run --verbose:

```
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="high_importance_channel" (Raw:
                   "high_importance_channel")
                 E: meta-data (line=82)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: service (line=86)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" 
                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=90)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.fireba                     se.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAu                     thRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=93)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.fireba                     se.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFireb                     aseFirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=96)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.fireba                     se.messaging.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFireb                     aseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=99)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.fireba                     se.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCo                     reRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=102)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.                     FirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar")  
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=105)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.fires                     tore.FirebaseFirestoreKtxRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreKtx                     Registrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=108)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.fires                     tore.FirestoreRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar")                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=111)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messa                     ging.FirebaseMessagingKtxRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingKtx                     Registrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=114)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messa                     ging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingReg                     istrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=117)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.R                     egistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=120)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.insta                     llations.FirebaseInstallationsKtxRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstalla                     tionsKtxRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=123)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.insta                     llations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstalla                     tionsRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=126)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.ktx.F                     irebaseCommonLegacyRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.ktx.FirebaseCommonLegacyRegist                     rar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=129)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.Fireb                     aseCommonKtxRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.FirebaseCommonKtxRegistrar")  
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=132)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datat                     ransport.TransportRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistr                     ar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"  
                     (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                 E: service (line=136)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessa                   gingBackgroundService" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService")  
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw:       
                   "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=140)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessa                   gingService" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: intent-filter (line=143)
                     E: action (line=144)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw:
                       "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")
                 E: receiver (line=148)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessa                   gingReceiver" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw:   
                   "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=152)
                     E: action (line=153)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw:      
                       "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                 E: provider (line=157)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessa                   gingInitProvider" (Raw:
                   "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingInitProvider")       
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A:
                   android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.kane.dealdiligence.flutterfirebasemessaginginit                   provider" (Raw: "com.kane.dealdiligence.flutterfirebasemessaginginitprovider")      
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x63
                 E: activity (line=163)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030007
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity" (Raw:  
                   "io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: activity (line=167)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"  
                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                   E: intent-filter (line=173)
                     E: action (line=174)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.VIEW" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.action.VIEW")
                     E: category (line=176)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                     E: category (line=177)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")
                     E: data (line=179)
                       A: android:scheme(0x01010027)="genericidp" (Raw: "genericidp")
                       A: android:host(0x01010028)="firebase.auth" (Raw: "firebase.auth")
                       A: android:path(0x0101002a)="/" (Raw: "/")
                 E: activity (line=185)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"   
                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                   E: intent-filter (line=191)
                     E: action (line=192)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.VIEW" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.action.VIEW")
                     E: category (line=194)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                     E: category (line=195)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")
                     E: data (line=197)
                       A: android:scheme(0x01010027)="recaptcha" (Raw: "recaptcha")
                       A: android:host(0x01010028)="firebase.auth" (Raw: "firebase.auth")
                       A: android:path(0x0101002a)="/" (Raw: "/")
                 E: receiver (line=204)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"    
                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw:   
                   "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=208)
                     E: action (line=209)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw:      
                       "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                   E: meta-data (line=212)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.FINISHED_AFTER_HAN                     DLED" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.FINISHED_AFTER_HANDLED")       
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 E: service (line=220)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=224)
                     A: android:priority(0x0101001c)=(type 0x10)0xfffffe0c
                     E: action (line=225)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" (Raw:
                       "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT")
                 E: provider (line=229)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"     
                   (Raw: "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.kane.dealdiligence.firebaseinitprovider"    
                   (Raw: "com.kane.dealdiligence.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 E: receiver (line=236)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"   
                   (Raw: "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=240)
                     E: action (line=241)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" (Raw:
                       "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY")
                 E: activity (line=245)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.revenuecat.purchases.amazon.purchasing.ProxyAmazonBill                   ingActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.revenuecat.purchases.amazon.purchasing.ProxyAmazonBillingActivity")
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x5b0
                 E: meta-data (line=250)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version" (Raw:   
                   "com.google.android.play.billingclient.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="6.1.0" (Raw: "6.1.0")
                 E: activity (line=254)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity"    
                   (Raw: "com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x5b0
                 E: activity (line=259)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"   
                   (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=264)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.extensions" (Raw:
                   "androidx.window.extensions")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=267)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.sidecar" (Raw:
                   "androidx.window.sidecar")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=271)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060001
                 E: provider (line=275)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" (Raw:
                   "androidx.startup.InitializationProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.kane.dealdiligence.androidx-startup" (Raw:  
                   "com.kane.dealdiligence.androidx-startup")
                   E: meta-data (line=279)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" (Raw:                     "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="androidx.startup" (Raw: "androidx.startup")
                 E: service (line=284)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.Transpor                   tBackendDiscovery" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery")      
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: meta-data (line=287)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendF                     actory" (Raw: "backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory")   
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="cct" (Raw: "cct")
                 E: service (line=291)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobsch                   eduling.JobInfoSchedulerService" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerS                   ervice")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw:       
                   "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=297)
                   A:
                   android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobsch                   eduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSched                   ulerBroadcastReceiver")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
[  +80 ms] Stopping app 'app-debug.apk' on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 
shell am force-stop com.kane.dealdiligence
[ +152 ms] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554
shell pm list packages com.kane.dealdiligence
[ +123 ms] package:com.kane.dealdiligence
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554
shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.kane.dealdiligence.sha1
[ +132 ms] 4b704d6308a8e0418baf4298517b579e9f0fe514
[   +1 ms] Latest build already installed.
[        ] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 
shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +145 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    01-17 11:13:05.255 D/CarrierSvcBindHelper( 1406): No carrier app for: 0
[  +16 ms] executing: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554
shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.kane.dealdiligence/com.kane.deal_diligence.MainActivity
[ +170 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.kane.dealdiligence/com.kane.deal_diligence.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +3 ms] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I had a typo in the name still.

Thanks for your help